# How do I add user custom meta data in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I want to add user metadata to WordPress, it should store only numbers, these numbers should support addition and subtraction
Please, how do I add it

The default value should be 0

Comment: You should show how you try to solve the problem. SO is not a coding workforce.

Answer (score 0):

You can add or update user meta data using below code

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'zip_code', $input['zip_code'] );

add_user_meta( $user_id, 'zip_code', $input['zip_code'] );

Comment: But, I'm talking about numbers, not zip codes, numbers I can modify using php arithmetic functions (addition and substraction)

Answer (score 0):

Try ACF, here is an example for using ACF fields inside users: https://usersinsights.com/acf-user-profile/